# Flutter, how to add tab button on side?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to implement like this

I don`t mind if it is just button or tab button

please click the image

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Rob I just searched for this for few hours. and then still didn\`t got answer for it

Comment: why don't you try to place the button on the left side inside a column widget? what prevents you from doing so?

Comment: @aumdlaqe Try `Transform` Widget. It'll help you achieve this.

Comment: @Darish I just want to add like tab buttons on side but I haven`t got example for this. this thing is more complicated because I want to put normal contents in center at the same time also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Method 1:** There is a flutter package to handle this.  It's called vertical_tabs and can be found at this location:[vertical_tabs 0.2.0](https://pub.dev/packages/vertical_tabs)

Make sure to add

```
vertical_tabs: ^0.2.0
```

to your pubspec.yaml file.

There is a full example on the [example page](https://pub.dev/packages/vertical_tabs#-example-tab-)

**Method 2:** If the above is too confining for your design needs, you can always build your own using a TabBar that is embedded in a Row() and RotatedBox() (this might give you the flexibility to do the rotate buttons that you seem to have in your example):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      RotatedBox(
        quarterTurns: 1,
        child: TabBar(
          controller: _tabController,
          tabs: <Widget>[
            getItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.person,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              text: Text(
                "Tab #1",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              ),
            ),
            getItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.done,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              text: Text(
                "Tab #2",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              ),
            ),
            getItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.dashboard,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              text: Text(
                "Tab #3",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: NewScreen(
          title: title,
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: I tried it and well this is not perfect example for mine but it gives me inspiration and helped a lot on other side. thanks

Comment: @aumdlaqe Thank you! Sorry it wasn’t an exact fit. I updated my answer to show a more ‘homegrown’ methodology. I hope maybe that can help you as well.